# Tooltip on custom button in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Came a cross this fiddle in the Highcharts API doc: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/buttons-text/

```
printButton: {
                text: 'Print',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.print();
                }
            }
```

As you can see from hovering over "print" or "download", the tooltip is undefined.

So, my question, simply, where do I define it?

Best regards :)

Comment: What do you mean undefined? I see no errors in my console log.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to add custom tooltip text for a button, you must add a 'lang' object in the chart's options, and define a key with some text.

Then use that key in the custom button's definition.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        // your chart options
    },
    lang: {
       yourKey: "Custom button tooltip text"
    },
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            yourCustomButton: {
                text: "Click me",
                _titleKey: "yourKey",
                onclick: function() {
                    // button functionality goes here
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7wEEj/

Comment: Thank you. Solved it with jQuery, but this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: How to add nspopover for the custom button.

Answer (score 2):

Add directly `_titleKey`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/x36qR/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that the lang option works even if the button is not *custom*.
For instance,

```
lang: {
    myKey: "Hello"
},
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        exportButton: {
            _titleKey:"myKey",
            enabled: true
        },
        printButton: {
            enabled: true
                }
           }
    }, ...
```

gives you the possibility to translate the tooltips of the export and print button.